# Jquery slider help

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

ok so i have an interspire shopping cart so its hard to customize..

anyway,

here is a link to my code 
http://jsfiddle.net/WTvQX/

im having trouble getting the scroll to work properly...

it works differently on my actual site here...

so i need help... re-doing it or just fixing..

let me kno

Comment: Neither of them seem to be working that great. What effect are you going for?

Comment: i know they aren't working great. thats why im asking for help! lol um lemme see... something like http://themes.dapurpixel.com/rumahbatik/14-ipod-yellow.html 
near the bottom is a slider... pretty much your average slider. i just cant find a pre-built one that has worked so i tried to do one myself.. any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the "relatedLeft" ID to the left button, however try something like this...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/WTvQX/3/

```
$('#relatedRight').click(function() {
    $('#scool').animate({left: "+=100px"}, 'slow');
});
$('#relatedLeft').click(function() {
    $('#scool').animate({left: "-=100px"}, 'slow');
});
```

You can adjust pixel distance and speed to your liking.

---

EDIT: Try something like this. The first part finds the width of all the images. Then the animates only fire when the offset is within range.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/WTvQX/5/

```
var w = 0;
$('#scroll img').each(function (i, val) {
    w += $(this).width();
});

$('#relatedRight').click(function() {
    var offset = $('#scroll').offset();
    if (offset.left < w) {
        $('#scroll').animate({left: "+=100px"}, 'slow');
    }
});
$('#relatedLeft').click(function() {
    var offset = $('#scroll').offset();
    if (offset.left > -w) {
        $('#scroll').animate({left: "-=100px"}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

---

EDIT: One more code option here. This one will stop scrolling sooner (note there are CSS changes here also).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/WTvQX/7/

```
var w = 0;
$('#scroll img').each(function (i, val) {
    w += $(this).width();
    w += parseFloat($(this).css('paddingRight'));
    w += parseFloat($(this).css('paddingLeft'));
    w += parseFloat($(this).css('marginRight'));
    w += parseFloat($(this).css('marginLeft'));
});

$('#scroll').css('width', w + 'px');

$('#relatedRight').click(function() {
    var offset = $('#scroll').offset();
    if (offset.left < 0) {
        $('#scroll').stop().animate({left: "+=100px"}, 'slow');
    }
});
$('#relatedLeft').click(function() {
    var offset = $('#scroll').offset();
    var b = $('#bar').width();
    if (offset.left > b-w) {
        $('#scroll').stop().animate({left: "-=100px"}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: awesome. that works great. um but can i bug you for one more thing... it will keep scrolling on, and on, and on. how would i get it to stop. lets say at the max distance of the ul or where ever the li's stop

Comment: or like if it gets to the end and you click again it goes back to left:0px... thanks again you've helped me out a lot. =)

Comment: is there like a min/max i can add to it?

Comment: hmmm no it doesn't seem to work on either the jsfiddle or when i transferred it to my site...

Comment: nvm i got it i made a few changes and its working how i needed it.. thank you for all your help

Comment: No problem, I posted one more code block just in case. This one will stop scrolling while still keeping the box filled with the images for the most part.